# Problem with making camera follow player in Javascript

Tags: javascript, camera, html

So I'm testing a few things in Javascript and something I was testing was making the camera follow the player. When I move the player, instead of the dots going away from the player, they follow the player and it looks very strange.

Here is the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLgEPO?editors=0010

Move the player using the arrow keys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just inverted the signs. The player's position should be the negative one and the canvas position, the positive one:

```
c.translate(-p.x, -p.y);
c.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
```

The reason for this is that `canvas.translate` makes a given point be considered `(0,0)` for all other drawing operations. The player is going to be rendered at position `p.x` and `p.y`. So if you want to make the player always stay at the point `(400, 400)` or `(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2)` you need to make `(0, 0)` become a value that added the current player position it will become `(400, 400)`. That value is: `(400 - p.x, 400 - p.y)`. You were previously subtracting 400 from the player position when the right is to subtract the player position from 400. A more consize code would be to replace those 2 lines with this one:

```
c.translate(canvas.width/2-p.x, canvas.height/2-p.y);
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked just how I wanted.